# Is It possible for a UItableview to have negative spacing in-between rows?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a UItableview, where I'd like all the cells to sort of overlap the next one, so to speak. Is it possible to set the spacing of two cells to e.g. -25?

Thanks

Comment: why do you need that indeed . What is your requirement could you clarify that.

Comment: Can u post ur screenshot? How design would be ?